# Duda pretérito perfecto e imperfecto

Tags: verbos, tiempos-verbales, pretérito

Estoy corrigiendo un texto sobre una película, tratando de ayudar a un amigo que está aprendiendo español, y tengo una duda sobre el uso del pretérito perfecto e imperfecto. Cuantas más vueltas le doy, más dudo. Incluso a veces el presente me parece válido también...

> Me encantó la película porque ***fue/era/es*** muy divertida. [...]
>   La escena final ***fue/era/es*** la más emocionante, ya que el protagonista [...].
>   En general me encantó y la recomendaría a los espectadores porque ***fue/era/es*** adecuada para toda la familia.

Yo cada vez que lo leo me parece que la opción adecuada es diferente :) ¿Sabríais decirme cuál sería la mejor opción en cada caso? Y sobre todo, ¿por qué?

*P.D: planteo la pregunta así en forma de "ejercicio", pero más que las opciones correctas me interesa una explicación de por qué...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En efecto, puedes usar el presente en los tres casos tranquilamente, porque la película sigue existiendo y sigue teniendo las mismas características. En el tercer caso, de hecho, no puedes usar otra opción: si utilizaras el pretérito, la estarías recomendando (para que la vean en el futuro) usando cualidades del pasado. Esa mezcla de futuro (aunque sea implícito) y pasado no funciona.

En las dos primeras opciones sí puedes usar un pretérito, aunque son un tanto diferentes. Para el primer caso no es correcto el indefinido, pues darías a entender que ya no tiene esa cualidad (ser muy divertida), cosa que no tiene demasiado sentido. Pero sí el imperfecto: hablas de una cualidad que tenía la película mientras la veías, pero no cierras la posibilidad de que la siga teniendo (de hecho, es de esperar que así sea).

En cambio, en el segundo caso puedes usar las tres opciones, aunque con significados ligeramente diferentes. Si usas el indefinido, hablas de una cualidad del pasado; pero esto puede tener sentido si hablas de una situación concreta. Es decir: fue la más emocionante para ti en ese momento, tal vez por circunstancias especiales; pero eso no significa que lo sea en general. Si no, estamos de nuevo en el primer caso.

En resumen:

> Me encantó la película porque **era/es** muy divertida. [...]
>
> La escena final **fue/era/es** la más emocionante, ya que el protagonista [...].
>
> En general me encantó y la recomendaría a los espectadores porque **es** adecuada para toda la familia.

Answer (score 2):

La explicación tendría que ver con las secuencias de tiempo que es un tema complicadísimo de describir con reglas fijas pero intento aplicar las ideas a tus oraciones para que tengas la idea.

> Me encantó la película …

Aquí nos orientamos en la primera cláusula en el tiempo pretérito y las cláusulas que dependen de ella tienen que flexionarse relativas a ella.

Si la razón por la que me gustó la película se podría describir como algo coetáneo con mi disfruto de ella, usamos el pretérito imperfecto (que también tiene el nombre de «copretérito», es decir, que ocurre mientras pasa una acción pretérita).  Si la razón es por algo ocurrido *antes* de cuando la vi, usamos el pluscuamperfecto (también conocido como el «antecopretérito», es decir, antes del momento en que pasa una acción pretérita).<sup>1</sup>  Si la razón es por algo que va a pasar, usamos o el condición (también conocido como el «pospretérito») o la secuencia perifrástica *ir a …* en el pretérito imperfecto.

Cuando se usa *porque*, la próxima cláusula (la que explica la anterior) tiene que someterse a estas reglas y así podemos entender la secuencia de tiempo.

- Me encantó la película porque …

  - *había leído* (en que se basaba) <sub>***un tiempo antes***</sub>
  - *leyera* el libro (en que se basaba) <sub>***un tiempo antes*** (muy poco común)</sub>
  - *hube visto* la primera (en la serie) <sub>***justo antes*** (poco común)</sub>
  - *estaba* con mis amigos (en el cine) <sub>***durante***</sub>
  - *saldríamos* (para helado) <sub>***después***</sub>
  - *íbamos a salir* (para helado) <sub>***después***</sub>

No son posibles otras formas porque contradicen la lógica temporal:

- Me encantó la película porque …

  - *tiene* mis actores favoritos <sub>***¿Los tiene ahora pero no cuando lo viste?***</sub>
  - *ganará* un Óscar <sub>***Imposible saberlo en el momento, ¿te lo dijo tu ser futuro o algo?***</sub>

Así que en la primera oración, optaría por «era».

En la segunda oración, dependerá de si, en esta parte del texto, se usa el presente histórico o no.  Si no, rigen las normas, pues, normales.  Si sí se usa, debe ser *es* y el resto de los verbos (después del *porque*) se rigen bajo normas parecidas a las que expliqué.

En la tercera, es más interesante porque tenemos tres cláusulas.  De la primera, «me encantó», no depende ninguna otra oración.  La segunda está en el condicional que en este contexto, siendo no intercambiable con su forma perifrástica «iba a recomendar», está situado más o menos en el presente.<sup>2</sup>  Por eso, seguir con el presente sería más recomendable, aunque serían admitibles las otras formas.  (pero nota que si tuviésemos un verbo con una situación temporal más definida como «recomendaré», «recomiendo», «recomendé», etc., las opciones sería más limitidas según la opción)

Espero haberlo explicado más o menos bien.  Yo también a veces doy vueltas pensando en qué tiempo debe ir algún verbo.

---

<sup>1. Puede ser admitible el pretérito anterior, también conocido el antepretérito, cuando las acciones se ven como una secuencia (normalmente cuando la acción anterior pasa justo antes de la acción posterior).  Es bastante desusado en la actualidad.</sup>
<sup>2. La situación precisa tanto temporal como modal del condicional es algo bastante discutida en la gramática española.</sup>

Comment: @MikO Acabo de ver que eres gallego, así que donde puse *muy poco común* para *leyera*, a lo mejor para ti no lo es, porque el gallego es como el portugués y el asturiano y mantiene el uso indicativo si recuerdo bien.

Comment: +1. Gracias por tu ayuda! Muy completa, sin embargo la otra respuesta me ha "llegado" un poco mejor, por decirlo de alguna manera.