# Differences between "era" and "fue"

Tags: pretérito-perfecto, pretérito-imperfecto

I have these two sentences:

> Picasso **era** uno de los artistas mejores de siglo veinte.
>   <sub>(Picasso was one of the best artists of the 20th century)</sub>
>
> Pablo Picasso **era** un pintor y escultor.
>   <sub>(Pablo Picasso was a painter and sculptor)</sub>

I don't know if I need to use *era* or *fue*!

What I know already:

*Era* (imperfect):

- talk about people or things in the past
- no definite beginning or end
- talk about time and descriptions in past

*Fue* (preterite):

- definite beginning or end
- actions taken by people or things in the past

I want to use `era` because we still call him an artist today, and some may say be still is one of the best artists of the 20th century

But, I was thinking about using *fue* because he is dead and him being an artist and sculptor came to an end.

Comment: I'd say both could work in the second sentence. I'd go with `fue` in the first one. Can't really justify my choices though (so I'll leave this as a comment), but they seem to agree with the criteria you provided. Also, I have a feeling uses of `era` and `fue` might be regional.

Comment: Possibly related: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/9813/6804

Answer (score 12):

> *Picasso was one of the best artists of the 20th century*
>
> Picasso **fue** uno de los mejores artistas de siglo veinte.

Here *fue* is better because we are speaking of a "definite" past, we are stating a past "concluded" fact, from the point of view of the present.

> Pablo Picasso was a painter and sculptor.

Here we have less context, hence the decision "fue/era" is ambiguous. If, say, that phrase is the beginning of a Wikipedia-like article, then the sense is roughly the same as before, hence *fue* is the correct alternative.

Suppose instead that we are in the middle of a narrative. We are writing about the life of Max Jacob and we assume that the reader does not necessarily knows who Picasso was.

> In 1900 Max Jacob met Picasso in Paris. *Pablo Picasso was a painter and sculptor* that had just come from Spain, and Max helped him with the French language.

A correct translation would be:

> En 1900 Max Jacob conoció a Picasso en París. Pablo Picasso **era** un pintor y escultor que recién había llegado desde España, y Max lo ayudó con el idioma francés.

Here we must use *era* because we are speaking of past fact (the occupation of Picasso) but from the point of view of that same past (i.e., relative to that perspective, the event "Picasso was a painter" is a "present continuous" event, something that "was happening" and which was not concluded at that time).

All this is not specific to the "ser/estar" verb, but rather to the general indefinite/imperfect past tenses in Spanish; see eg [here](http://spanish.about.com/od/verbtenses/a/two_past_tenses.htm).

Update: 
Regarding

> I want to use *era* because we still call him an artist today, and some may say be still is one of the best artists of the 20th century

To emphasize that aspect, you would not use *era*: you would simply use the present (just as you wrote in English) "Picasso es uno de los mejores artistas", or to be more precise and avoid confusion: "Picasso es considerado uno de los mejores artistas" (he is regarded as one of the best artists...) or "Picasso está entre los mejores artistas" (he is among the best artists...) In these later cases, it would be wrong to use the past tense, because the verb (to be) does not refer to Picasso's past life or ocuppation (who was he? what did he do?) but to his present position.

Comment: Very good answer.  And it's even possible to use to imperfect in the first one, in a sentence like *Era uno de los mejores... hasta que [pret.]*.   Context is crucial for determining pret/imp.

Answer (score 6):

Ambas formas denotan una acción pasada. La diferencia entre perfecto e imperfecto no tiene que ver con una acción acabada o inacabada, al contrario de lo que dicen algunos. Es una cuestión "topológica" (me refiero a una rama de las matemáticas).

Voy a dar una explicación matemática que quizá no todos entiendan:

Situémonos en la *recta* del tiempo. El momento presente es un punto en ella. El pasado está a un lado y el futuro al otro.

- *Era* (imperfecto) es como un intervalo abierto.
- *Fue* (perfecto) es como un punto, que se enmarca dentro de un intervalo abierto (explícito o implícito en el contexto). Ese intervalo es un *entorno abierto* del punto. Se corresponde con un período temporal (en el que se enmarca el hecho puntual del que hablamos).

¿Qué significa esto? Ejemplos:

- Mientras conducía [intervalo abierto] me distraje [hecho puntual] y por eso atropellé [hecho puntual] al ciclista.
- Esa semana fue [hecho puntual] la más dura de todo el mes [el mes es el intervalo que nos enmarca la semana].
- En el ejemplo de la respuesta anterior, *Pablo Picasso era un pintor y escultor que...*, leonbloy mismo explica que el conexto implícito es que Picasso, como el punto de vista se sitúa en el momento en el que Max Jacob le conoció [hecho puntual], estaba vivo antes y después de ese hecho, es un "entorno" del punto. O sea, le conoció [punto] cuando Picasso era pintor y escultor [intervalo abierto, porque estaba vivo y ejercía de ello durante ese período de tiempo].

Por eso la diferencia entre uno y otro la marca el contexto: depende de cómo situemos las cosas en el tiempo, usaremos un verbo u otro.

Es similar a la contraposición *continuous*-*simple* en inglés. De la misma manera, normalmente usaremos el adverbio *mientras* con el pretérito imperfecto (es el entorno) y la locución adverbial *de repente* con el pretérito perfecto (es el hecho puntual):

- Mientras conducía me distraje y atropellé al ciclista.
- Conducía cuando, de repente, me distraje.

Ah, y, en efecto, es "Picasso fue...* porque se trata de un hecho puntual. En otro caso (*Picasso era...*), estaríamos indicado que eso es el contexto (marco temporal) de un hecho puntual aún por mencionar.

Pero si estás hablado del concepto de los considerados artistas acualmente, lo más correcto es: *Picasso es uno de los mejores artistas del siglo XX / que ha habido en el siglo XX.* Pues aunque ya no es pintor, porque murió, sigue siendo considerado un artista. Para transmitir esta idea hay que usar *es*;  y *era* no encaja para nada.

Igual que podríamos decir: *Platón es el filósofo que instruyó a Aristóteles*, igual de correcto que *Platón fue el filósofo que instruyó a Aristóteles*. En este caso los dos son válidos, con ligeros matices de diferencia.