# My questions is about the distinction between el tiempo pasado and el imperfecto

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, pretérito-imperfecto

Why is it that people use **¿Cómo fueron tus vacaciones?** instead of **¿Cómo eran tus vacaciones?**

I thought that when you're decribing situations you should use *el imperfecto* and *el pasado* is only used when you're doing things consecutively or when there is a specific time?

Comment: Does this post http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/9969/differences-between-era-and-fue?rq=1 help?

Comment: It's `el imperfecto` and `el tiempo pasado`.. not `indefinido`